# How to print IPA characters with mvn:exec?

Tags: java, maven, utf-8, character-encoding, nlp

I've the following simply program that prints the IPA word `ˈabsəluːt` [1]. Unfortunately executing this program with `mvn:exec` prints the word as `?abs?lu?t`[2]. How to make it print it correctly, i.e. as in [1]?

```
    package dp4j.encodingtest;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "ˈabsəluːt";
        System.out.println(s);
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("s.txt"), s);
    }
}
```

The `mvn exec:exec` command:

```
mvn "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath dp4j.encodingtest.App" 
-Dexec.executable=C:\\jdk1.7.0_25\\bin\\java.exe exec:exec
```

Even printing the word to the s.txt file doesn't print it is incorrectly as in [2].

Comment: Does it print to a control in a window or to the console?

Comment: to the console: http://screencast.com/t/IKely5Etyw

Comment: That's probably your issue then. The console doesn't always play well with unicode or extended character sets.

Comment: hmm..so how to get it out correctly? I've tried to even print the word to a file but to no avail.

Comment: If you print to a file, make sure you specify an encoding that will display it properly. Ultimately I think it is an encoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the application where that word is displayed/printed, in this case, the console. Nothing can be done from java / maven except to make sure your java source code encoding is UTF-8 (as string literal is used).

If you are running it from an IDE, then try to change the console font from IDE's options/preferences to ‘Lucida Sans’ as this font has partial support for IPA extensions or some other available fonts with IPA support.